# Daily update from file with prefix and dynamic numbers from other files

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a file that contains two columns, month (in number format) and year that I need to update in my file daily. From the months that I had, I will refer to a data set with a prefix 'member_' follow by month.

I have tried the following, but it does not work. Can anyone provide solution for this?

```
DECLARE @row VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @RMonth VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @RYear VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @MAXrow NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @MAX_row VARCHAR(1)

SET @MAX_row=(SELECT MAX([row]) FROM #refresh)
SET @row=1 WHILE @row<=@MAX_row

BEGIN

SELECT @RMonth =N'SELECT @RMonth = RMonth FROM #refresh WHERE [row]='+@row
EXEC sp_executesql @RMonth, N'@RMonth NVARCHAR(2) OUTPUT', @RMonth OUTPUT

select 
memberid,
sales,
'+@RMONTH+' as Rmonth,
'+@RYEAR+' as Ryear
from member_'+@RMonth'
```

If the months appear in my file is 11, 12 and 1 with year 2018, 2018,2019 respectively, then I will extract data from data set member_11, member_12 and member_1. (Please note that the member data set stored is only 12 months, thus link to the months will do.)

1. How can I use SQL query to enable me to auto extract the member data set based on the numbers in another data set and union these three files?
2. Also, I would like to have the month and year to be appeared as new columns in the member data set.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh, MSSQL Server Management Studio

Comment: FYI SSMS is not a database, its a client access program to a database.